# Can this function be integrated and, if so, what is its value?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Say I have a piecewise function defined as:

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if x is irrational} \\
1/q &\text{if x = $p/q$, where $p,q > 0$ are relatively prime integers} \\
\end{cases}$

over the interval $[0,1]$.  I can prove that $f$ is continuous over the irrational numbers and discontinuous at all rational numbers.  But, is the function Riemann integrable:
$\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$?  If so how would I prove it and what would be the value?  Intuition suggests that the value would be zero but I'm at a loss for how to proceed.  Assuming the function IS Riemann integrable could I split it up into multiple sections at every discontinuity?  But, there are infinitely many discontinuities...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, you mean to say it is discontinuous at the rationals. Second, Lebesgue's criteria for Riemann integration says that a function is Riemann integrable iff it is discontinuous on a set of Lebesgue measure zero. The rationals are measure zero.

Comment: Intuitively: R-integrability means you can cut the domain of integration into finitely many intervals such that the oscillation (high point minus low point) is small for each interval. Because you can make intervals where the size of the denominators is similar, you achieve this. (This is similar to the proof that this function is continuous only at irrationals)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Lebesgue's Criterion, a function is Reimann integrable iff it is bounded and the set of discontinuities has measure $0$, i.e. countable. In this case, $|f|\leq1$, and the set of discontinuities is $\mathbb{Q}$ which is countable and thus measure $0$. So, the function $f$ is Reimann integrable.

For any function which is Reimann integrable, it is also Lebesgue integrable, and the value of each integral is equivalent. Hence, it suffices to find the Lebesgue integral of $f$. To do this, consider that $f$ is piecewise constant, and nonzero on a set of measure $0$, so it has Lebesgue integral $\int f = 0$, and so the Reimann integral is also $0$.

Comment: Would prefer an argument that uses Riemann integration.  But I like the statement about countable discontinuities.

Comment: @IdleMathGuy: Even proving the Riemann integrability of functions with countable discontinuities is non-trivial without measure theory. The key idea is to use Riemann's criterion which says that the total size of intervals where oscillation of a function is greater than some specific number can be smaller than any given bound.